# UTF 8 String remove all invisible characters except newline

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, newline

I'm using the following regex to remove all invisible characters from an UTF-8 string:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\p{C}+/u', '', $string);
```

This works fine, but how do I alter it so that it removes all invisible characters EXCEPT newlines? I tried some stuff using [^\n] etc. but it doesn't work.

Thanks for helping out!

Edit: newline character is '\n'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a "double negation":

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\P{C}\n]+/u', '', $string);
```

**Explanation:**

- `\P{C}` is the same as `[^\p{C}]`.
- Therefore `[^\P{C}]` is the same as `\p{C}`.
- Since we now have a negated character class, we can substract other characters like `\n` from it.

Answer (score 2):

My using a negative assertion you can a character class except what the assertion matches, so:

```
$res = preg_replace('/(?!\n)\p{C}/', '', $input);
```

(PHP's dialect of regular expressions doesn't support character class subtraction which would, otherwise, be another approach: `[\p{C}-[\n]]`.)

Comment: I tried, it doesn't remove newlines, also it doesn't remove other invisible characters (both approaches)

Comment: @Stefan It is meant to not remove newlines: see title of Q "*except* newline".

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I meant is does remove newlines.

Comment: @Stefan Just tested. Created a file with `\n` only line endings (ie. Unix). Ran that regex over it: nothing was replaced. With a Windows file (`\r\n` line endings) the carriage returns were replaced but not the newlines. (PHP maps lone `\r` or `\n` to `\r\n` on output, so `\n` could be reappearing: this messed up my test initially.)

Answer (score 0):

Before you do it, replace newlines (I suppose you are using something like `\n`) with a random string like `++++++++` (any string that will not be removed by your regular expression and does not naturally occur in your string in the first place), then run your preg_replace, then replace `++++++++` with `\n` again.

```
$string=str_replace('\n','++++++++',$string); //Replace \n
$string=preg_replace('/\p{C}+/u', '', $string); //Use your regexp
$string=str_replace('++++++++','\n',$string); //Insert \n again
```

That should do. If you are using `<br/>` instead of `\n` simply use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to preserve line breaks and replace `<br/>` instead of `\n`

Comment: \n it is. What you described is what I'm using at this moment but I don't really think it's that neat as the regex could do it (I think, but don't know how)