# Removing control characters from a UTF-8 string in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, utf-8

So I am removing control characters (tab, cr, lf, \v and all other invisible chars) in the client side (after input) but since the client cannot be trusted, I have to remove them in the server too.

so according to this link http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

the control characters are from x00 to 1F and from 7F to 9F.
thus my client (javascript) control char removal function is:

```
return s.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, "");
```

and my php (server) control char removal function is:

```
$s = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/', '', $s);
```

Now this seems to create problems with international utf8 chars such as ς (xCF x82) in PHP only (because x82 is inside the second sequence group), the javascript equivalent does not create any problems.

Now my question is, should I remove the control characters from 7F to 9F? To my understanding those the sequences from 127 to 159 (7F to 9F) obviously can be part of a valid UTF-8 string?

also, maybe I shouldn't even filter the 00 to 31 control characters because also some of those characters can appear in some weird (japanese? chinese?) but valid utf-8 characters ?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12543476/1066234 It is a different regex.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it seems that I just need to add the *u* flag to the regex
thus it becomes:

```
$s = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/u', '', $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

> should I remove the control characters from 7F to 9F? To my understanding those the sequences from 127 to 159 (7F to 9F) obviously can be part of a valid UTF-8 string?

You should not, except for `\x7F`, which is represented as `\x7F` in UTF-8, because they’re lower surrogates in UTF-8.

---

> maybe I shouldn't even filter the 00 to 31 control characters because also some of those characters can appear in some weird (japanese? chinese?) but valid utf-8 characters ?

Those control characters are still control characters in UTF-8. The presence of them may mean a Mojibake; if you want to correct it, preserve them, otherwise, filter them out.