# Remove ¶-symbol from CSV import

Tags: php, csv, replace, paragraph

I'm importing a CSV file, but for some reason, every line ends with the ¶-symbol... So my database is contaminated with all this symbol. And above all, it's ruining my workflows.

So I would like to strip those symbols.

I've tried with `$csv_value = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $csv_value);` but this line of code also deleted my spaces...

How can I just remove the ¶ symbol from my `$csv_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¶ - it is newline symbol, try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', $csv_value);
```

This question already answered, other examples you can find on this link:
[PHP: How to remove all non printable characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but still not solution :(

Comment: Indeed, this was my solution!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The ¶ symbol is denoted as a line break, so try this:

```
$csv_value = preg_replace( '/\n+/', '', $csv_value);
```