# Base64 Decode in php with a json_decode

Tags: php

Hi i have the following issue where in some instances the json_decode does not work and i get an empty array as follows.

```
// for test purpose set the inbound enc parameter
$_POST["enc"] = "eyJ0cmFuc2NyaXB0IjoiLSAgICAgICAgICBQYXN0ZWQgdGhlIHRleHQgaW50byBOb3RlcGFkIBMgbm8gc3BlY2lhbCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIiwiaWQiOjcwLCJpc0FjdGlvbmVkIjp0cnVlLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ0YXNrX3R5cGVfaWQiOjEsImFjY291bnRfaWQiOjIxLCJhY2NvdW50X25hbWUiOiJURVNUIiwiZXZlbnRfZGF0ZSI6bnVsbH0=";

$decoded = base64_decode($_POST["enc"]);
$ar = (array)json_decode($decoded);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($decoded);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ar);
echo "</pre>";
```

`$decoded` displays as a json string, but `$ar` is `null`.

Any help please will be appreciated in helping me with this issue.

Comment: Have you run the string though http://jsonlint.com to verify it is valid JSON?

Comment: Can you attach the output of $decoded ?

Comment: Have you then used the second parameter in `json_decode` to output as an array rather than an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your code and decoding the Base64 encoded string it turns out you have a `CHR(13)` ASCII character in your JSON data which is causing the JSON to fail validation according to [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/).  Taking that character out results in the JSON parsing correctly.

[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jgn-2wk)

Decoded JSON data:

```
{
    "transcript": "-          Pasted the text into Notepad  no special characters",
    "id": 70,
    "isActioned": true,
    "user_id": 1,
    "task_type_id": 1,
    "account_id": 21,
    "account_name": "TEST",
    "event_date": null
}
```

HEX Editor Screenshot:
[image: HEX Editor Screenshot]

Comment: You are correct on the extra char the user copied and pasted from  an email and it was a long minus sign, how can i ensure that all chars get handled correctly is really the main point here.

Comment: If you are able to correct the string before it is JSON encoded that would be the best way to fix the problem. Possibly a regular expression could remove non standard characters something like `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string)` will remove all non-printable characters (regex from answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1176923/2594742)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't supply the second parameter in `json_decode` to return as an array, and not an object

```
// for test purpose set the inbound enc parameter
$_POST["enc"] = "eyJ0cmFuc2NyaXB0IjoiLSAgICAgICAgICBQYXN0ZWQgdGhlIHRleHQgaW50byBOb3RlcGFkIBMgbm8gc3BlY2lhbCBjaGFyYWN0ZXJzIiwiaWQiOjcwLCJpc0FjdGlvbmVkIjp0cnVlLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ0YXNrX3R5cGVfaWQiOjEsImFjY291bnRfaWQiOjIxLCJhY2NvdW50X25hbWUiOiJURVNUIiwiZXZlbnRfZGF0ZSI6bnVsbH0=";

$decoded = base64_decode($_POST["enc"]);
$ar = json_decode($decoded, true); //<-- Now returned as an array, and not an object

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($decoded);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ar);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output**

```
{"transcript":"-          Pasted the text into Notepad  no special characters","id":70,"isActioned":true,"user_id":1,"task_type_id":1,"account_id":21,"account_name":"TEST","event_date":null}
```

Comment: ...because it doesn't work... it's valid to cast an object as an array. The error is with his raw `JSON`, not the `PHP`.

Comment: [Online JSON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) & [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) both say it's valid here.

Comment: Remove the `print_r($decoded)` and your script won't output anything, as `$ar` will still be `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your `JSON` - oddly in the two spaces between "Notepad" and "no".

It looks like there's a nonstandard character between the spaces. Remove that character and the JSON is valid.

**Invalid**

```
{"transcript":"- Pasted the text into Notepad  no special characters","id":70,"isActioned":true,"user_id":1,"task_type_id":1,"account_id":21,"account_name":"TEST","event_date":null}
```

**Valid**

```
{"transcript":"- Pasted the text into Notepad  no special characters","id":70,"isActioned":true,"user_id":1,"task_type_id":1,"account_id":21,"account_name":"TEST","event_date":null}
```

In the future, ideally you would use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) to build your `JSON` string. The function will automatically escape any non-valid characters for you.

Comment: Correct answer, you beat me on time :)