# PHP JSON-String doesn't work correct

Tags: php, json

I have a `JSON-String` like

```
{"aaa":"foo", "bbb":"bar", "ccc":"hello", "ddd":"world"}
```

Actually I recive this string via `$_GET`. It is base64 encoded and if I decode it I have this string.

So further is want to use this in `PHP` as an `object`. For this is do

```
$data = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['data'] ) );
```

but `$data` is `NULL` all the time. If I do

```
echo base64_decode( $_GET['data'] );
```

Then the valid `JSON-String` is printed as expacted.

What am I doing wrong ?

I have tried to call the base64_encode before but same result...

Comment: Can you confirm when your print $_GET['data'] tht it is encoded.

Comment: Take a look at the source code of `var_dump(base64_decode($_GET['data']));`, maybe it's html encoded...

Comment: Might be a good idea to include the actual base64 string that you are trying to decode. Or at least the actual JSON data. have you tried to `echo json_last_error();` to see what error the json parser encounters?

Comment: It is simply not a valid JSON-string, since a non valid json-string returns NULL. Please provide the actual output of the base64_decode. There is something wrong there.

Comment: what is the output of $data = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['data'] ), true );

Comment: @fortune he said, its Null

Comment: Look at the actual source output of `echo base64_decode($_GET['data']);` rather than the browser-rendered result; as @HamZa says, perhaps you're getting `&quote;` rather than `"` in the data? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324645/problem-with-json-decode-php

Comment: added a edit to my post to answere all comments

Comment: This is not a forum - you do not answer comments by editing question!

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski so you want me to write 5 comments ?

Comment: But did you try to do what i actually said in my comments? Also, don't answer by edits, thats just silly!

Comment: @Dwza What do you mean "it's the same"? That even `json_decode( '{"aaa":"foo",....}');` doesn't work? If that's the case then you have a major problem. I hope you're not coding in MS-word :P

Comment: {"aaa":"foo",....} isnt even valid json so there you go, problem solved!

Comment: Sorry for editing my post and answere 5 questions to the same time... so ill go for comments end undid the changes in my post...

Comment: also, check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529843/base64-decode-in-php-with-a-json-decode might be related.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Yes i can. @HamZa No, its not. @ EJTH I also have tried to use `json_decode( '{"aaa":"foo",....}');` Its same. @HamZa I tested the string on Lint allready. @W van Rij jslint sayes its valid.

Comment: @EJTH yes i did and it returns 5. Could this be a UTF8 problem ?

Comment: did you try using `urldecode` before you call other functions? like `$data = json_decode(base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['data'])));`

Comment: @OzgurBar actually I don't need it since the json string is return as expacted but even with this I have the same result

Comment: If `json_last_error` returns 5 then it is very likely that the JSON you have is in fact not valid, as it contains malformed UTF-8 sequences. I really can't help you without seeing the data you are handling.

Comment: @EJTH You are right. Just found out the same... actually it's some german words like `straße` and `fußgänger` so I oviously have to transform the data into some like unicode or some...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `json_last_error()` and see what error the JSON parser encountered. If you encounter `5` then it is very likely that your JSON data contains unencoded UTF-8 sequences. You should always use a JSON-encoding library for handling data export to json.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php for a list of what errors you can handle with `json_last_error` (There is a INT to definition name table in the user comments)

```
0 = JSON_ERROR_NONE
1 = JSON_ERROR_DEPTH
2 = JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH
3 = JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR
4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8
```