# PHP function to securely encode characters for multiple purposes

Tags: php, mysql, security, encoding

I am trying to build a function (unless there is already one, I was not able to find one) that satisfies:

- being saved in a MySQL database →  `mysqli_real_escape_string`
- being saved in a serialized array in a MySQL database (I had issues when unserialize failed)

as for output:

- doesn't interfer with HTML →  `utf8_encode(htmlentities($source, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8'));`
- doesn't interfer with it being a query in an URL, thus encoding the '&','%'

Please give me any advice if there is an idea on how to improve secure encoding.
And I am not sure about the functions give, whether they are the best to be used.

I also had issues with non-printable characters and tried
[PHP: How to remove all non printable characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)
    `$s = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x80-\x9F]/u', '', $s);`

**EDIT**
Because of the diversity of this question, I want to substantiate the question on how to clean a string that is an element of an array that is put with `serialize()` in a database ´?

For instance, I had a failure when trying to unserialize after having put a string containing a newline (\n or \r) into an string element of an array that has been serialized successfully...

**EDIT_2**
The reason for why I have tried to issue encoding HTML entities *before* saving them into the DB using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is that when recalling/loading this object from the DB, the data has changed. For example a user wants to put the string `test'test` into the database that is encoded by `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to `test\'test` and then when loaded from the DB it's still `test\'test` whcih is *NOT* what the user wants to have neither what he has sent . Please if you could find a solution for this  --  mine was to apply sth. like where `mysqli_real_escape_string()` had no effect as the quotes have already been HTML encoded.

Comment: This is a very wrong-headed idea.  Database escaping is by its very nature a completely separate concept than output escaping.  Escape content *when you're emitting it* to a thing that needs escaping, never any earlier.  Please read the answer given in the dupe candidate.  The question isn't an exact dupe, but the *answer* totally is.

Comment: If you're getting *escaped* data from the database, please make sure that your PHP environment doesn't have the *poisonous*, **deprecated** (5.3), ***removed*** (5.4) "magic quotes" feature enabled.  See [`get_magic_quotes_runtime`](http://php.net/get_magic_quotes_runtime)

Comment: +1 what Charles said. There is no “global escape”, every escaping scheme is necessarily context specific. For HTML-escaping you should just use `htmlspecialchars` alone, at the point of inserting into the HTML page *not* anywhere near the database. There is no need for `utf8_encode` here. When you insert `mysql_real_escape_string`ed content into a string literal in an SQL query that is decoded at the database end before being used, so you will not find `\'` inside the database unless there is another problem. Better: use parameterised queries (in mysqli or PDO), avoiding escaping issues.

Comment: A byte string produced by `serialize()` may not fit in a database text column because it is arbitrary binary and not text (for example, your text collation might be UTF-8 and the output of `serialize()` may not be a valid UTF-8 byte sequence). You could use a BINARY column or a text-safe encoding like JSON, which would also avoid a bunch of security problems with `unserialize()` (essentially PHP serialized data acts somewhat like active code and so it's not a good idea to be executing it out of the database). Better: normalise the database schema so you can store list items in separate rows.

Comment: revised my db scheme and yes utf8_encode is not necessary on user inputs as they are already utf8 because a corresponding http header was sent (+ in the head I added the encoding as a meta tag); only when writing data like the useragent or the requested URI, I needed utf8_encode. now all fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head, I feel you should try [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly:  json_encode() will always preserve associative arrays while for json_decode() you need to set the corresponding paramter  to true? Do these function work **definitely** with all kind of strings (like those containing linebreaks or special chars like } which is a control character in Json)