# PHP - unserialize returns false on string from serialize.js

Tags: php, serialization

I'm serializing an object using `serialize.js`, I get this string:

```
a:4:{s:8:"option-1";i:0;s:8:"option-2";i:1;s:8:"option-3";i:0;s:8:"option-4";i:0;};
```

When I run unserialize in PHP, I get

> unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 5 of 123 bytes

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show the code how you unserialize your string

Comment: There seem to be several libraries that provide a Javascript `serialize` function. Which one are you using?

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried that, and it works if I do `unserialize('a:4:{s:8:"option-1";i:0;s:8:"option-2";i:1;s:8:"option-3";i:0;s:8:"option-4";i:0;};');`, however it doesn't work with `unserialize(trim($this->value()));` When I var_dump the `$this->value()`, I get the string... Lost here

Comment: The error which you have pasted is `Error at offset 5 of 123 bytes`, but the string is 84 bytes long. Are you sure this is the string you are having problems with?

Comment: That's indeed strange - when I do `die(var_dump($this->value()))`, I get `string(123) "a:4:{s:8:"option-1";i:0;s:8:"option-2";i:1;s:8:"option-3";i:0;s:8:"option-4";i:0;};"`

Comment: You have some weird characters as you can see from your comment - <200c><200b> when pasted in `vim`. Can you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string before `unserialize`?

Answer (score -1):

You most likely need to pass the serialized string through urlencode() before outputting.

To process it then, use urldecode() before unserialize().