# String comparison for "blank" Unicode characters in PHP

Tags: php, unicode

I'm trying to detect if a Unicode string is printable.

For example, I have a user who has set their name to `%EF%B8%8F` - which is [variation selector-16 (U+FE0F)](http://graphemica.com/%EF%B8%8F)

I want to be able to do something like

```
if ($screen_name == null || $screen_name == NotPrintable )
{
    ...Show an error...
} else  {
    ...Proceed as normal...
}
```

Is there any way to detect if a Unicode string is printable?

Users names can be any valid Unicode sequence (English, Chinese, Arabic, etc).

Some [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string#1176923) suggest complex regexes which look like they only work with a narrow range of characters.

I've tried counting the length of the string, but that doesn't work -

`$odd = urldecode("%EF%B8%8F");
   print strlen($odd);
   3`

Same result for `mb_strlen()` as well.

Functions like [`ctype_print()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-print.php) won't work because regular strings can contain non-printable characters.

So, is there any way to detect whether a Unicode string will display printable characters?

Answer (score 2):

Working from the [PHP regexp guide for unicode](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), I assume you want to keep all letters (L), Marks (M), Numbers (N), Punctuation (P), symbols (S) and spaces (Z) and dump everything else (such as control characters). Therefore, a regexp of:

```
$out=preg_replace('/[^\pL|\pM|\pN|\pP|\pS|\pZ]/u','',$in);
```

appears to do the trick.

[edit]

Well, that doesn't work with the provided

```
$in=urldecode('%EF%B8%8F');
```

example (which decodes to Unicode code point [U+FE0F / &#65039;](http://unicode-table.com/en/FE0F/). The following code does handle it:

```
$len=mb_strlen($in);
$out='';
$disallowedTypes=[IntlChar::CHAR_CATEGORY_NON_SPACING_MARK];
for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
 $char=mb_substr($in,$i,1);
 $type=IntlChar::charType($char);
 if (false===in_array($type,$disallowedTypes)) {
  $out.=$char;
  //print 'Adding ord '.dechex(IntlChar::ord($char)).' which is '.IntlChar::charType($char).PHP_EOL;
 }
}
```

but I'm not happy iterating through a string and comparing each character... Please let me know if you find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

What about this Regex?

```
<?php
define("CTYPE_PRINT_UNICODE_PATTERN", "~^[\pL\pN\s\"\~". preg_quote("!#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}´") ."]+$~u");

function ctype_print_unicode($input) {
    return preg_match(CTYPE_PRINT_UNICODE_PATTERN, $input);
}

print ctype_print_unicode("3 muços?"); // 1
```

Comment: It seems to work most of the time, but I'm not sure that I understand why! It also fails on some characters like `print ctype_print_unicode(urldecode("%E0%BF%94"));`