# Compare two strings PHP

Tags: php, string

I need compare two string. Visually they compare, but var_dump result other. Help me please.

string(8) "СИ.pdf"
string(7) "CИ.pdf"

How correct compare him?

Comment: Most likely the strings are in different encoding. You will have to find out why that is, so that you can prevent such thing in future. Do _not_ search for some automatic encoding conversion, _that will not work_. Use a `hexeditor` if you want to understand what you see.

Comment: you have to [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mb_convert_encoding() to convert both versions to something reasonable (UTF8 for example) then use mb_strstr() to do the comparison.

Comment: Thx! mb_convert_encoding($fileName) === mb_convert_encoding($item->getName()) work for me

Comment: it is bad answer

Comment: Really? Why? It worked for the OP. Do you have something better to suggest?

Answer (score -1):

most likely there are some non printable characters in the string

check out the following :
[PHP: How to remove all non printable characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)