# How to remove all non printable characters in a string and keep some?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters, non-printing-characters

I'm using this

`$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', $string);`

That regex is from this link [PHP: How to remove all non printable characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)

The regex is removing `\n` but I would like to keep it.
What should I do?

I think `\n` is `000A`, so I've tried something like this (it will make all the regex stoping working)
`$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0[ˆ\x0A]]/u', '', $string);`

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range `\x00-\x1F` contains `\x0A`.

You have to split this range.

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x09\x0B-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0[^\x0A^\x0d]]
```

**Explanation**:

x0A - line feed (\n)

x0d - carriage return  (\r)

**Example**:

https://regexr.com/3k3bm

Answer (score 1):

Minimal change to the original regex:

```
/(?!\n|\r)[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/u
```

Uses a negative lookahead to not match line feeds and carriage returns.