# An alternative in php to the xxd command in linux

Tags: php, bin, xxd, bin2hex

I need to convert the bin file to a string in PHP in the same way as the Linux program does.

In linux: `xxd -g 1 data.bin` and output: `0000000: 02 50 45 10 02 06 54 62 43 20 05 20 11 07 21 12  .PE...TbC . ..!.`

In PHP, I tried to use the `bin2hex` function, but i get only the digits `02 50 45 10 02 06 54 62 43 20 05 20 11 07 21 12`. I also need an offset and textual representation.

The offset is the line number, the first digits and a colon (`0000000:`) in the string I entered above. This is actually not a problem, because I can write code that calculates this, but the bigger problem is with textual representation (`.PE...TbC . ..!.`).

Someone can help? What functions could I use for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "offset"? Why not write code that calculates this offset?

Comment: @NicoHaase The offset is the line number, the first digits and a colon in the string I entered. This is actually not a problem, but the bigger problem is with textual representation.

Comment: Then please add all details to your question by editing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all non printable characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to replace [non-printable characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) with a `.` (or whatever character you choose).

```
$data = hex2bin('02504510020654624320052011072112');
$text_representation = preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '.', $data);
var_dump($text_representation);
```