# Some Unicode characters cannot be printed in PrinceXML

Tags: php, css, princexml

```
page 6: warning: no font for Basic Latin character U+000B, fallback to U+2BD1 ⯑
page 6: warning: Ensure fonts are available on the system or load them via a @font-face rule.
page 6: warning: For more information see:
page 6: warning: https://www.princexml.com/doc/help-install/#missing-glyphs-or-fonts
internal error: Unable to find any available fonts.
```

Hello guys! I'm getting the warnings/errors above when converting HTML to PDF using PrinceXML. In CSS my font is `font-family: serif !important;`.
Because of the error above Prince can't generate a PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out [Times New Roman](http://zuga.net/articles/unicode-all-characters-supported-by-the-font-times-new-roman/) is the default serif font in [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/doc/styling/#generic-font-families), and it cannot print [control characters (0000-000F)](http://zuga.net/articles/unicode/block/basic-latin/). So I just remove the control characters from a string before passing it to the PrinceXML as was suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string) (take a look at the accepted answer).

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

> internal error: Unable to find any available fonts.

It appears that the system you're running Prince on does not have any fonts installed. Since this is not usually possible on Windows or macOS systems I imagine you're on a UNIX-like system. I'd suggest installing the [Liberation fonts](https://github.com/liberationfonts/liberation-fonts) to get started. E.g. `fonts-liberation2` package on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I'm running the Debian Linux distribution. Sorry, forgot to mention that. But I do have the msttcorefonts installed on my server.
Most of the time Prince converts HTML to PDF correctly but when some weird Unicode symbols are added I get "no font for Basic Latin character U+000B, fallback to U+2BD1 ⯑" warning and Prince doesn't generate PDF.

Comment: Now, I've run Prince with debug option and it seems I do have Liberation fonts on my machine: "Thu Aug 18 07:33:05 2022: debug: font scan: liberation serif, 4 matches".

Comment: Hmm that is strange. As you note "no font for Basic Latin character U+000B, fallback to U+2BD1" is a warning and does not prevent Prince from generating a PDF, something else is causing that. It might be worth opening a thread on the Prince Forum and attaching your HTML & CSS to better diagnose the issue. https://www.princexml.com/forum/3/bugs

Comment: Well, as a workaround, I remove Control Characters (00-1F) from the input string. As my default serif font is Times New Roman and it doesn't support those control characters.
Another solution could be to add some font that supports the printing of those said characters.