# Remove degree symbol from string php

Tags: php

i have in database a string written with degree symbol, problem is when im printing it im getting it with unicode, each unicode is different even they are the same symbol, its driving me crazy how can replace the degree symbol for white space, im doing it this way:

```
 foreach ($video as $desc) {
          if (preg_match('/\/(.*?)"E/', $desc, $match) == 1) {
                $test = preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7E]/', '', $match[1]);
                echo $test;
            }
         }
```

and my output is:

```
22\u00b017'44.1\"N, 114\u00b010'07.7\ 
22\u00b016'55.5\"N, 114\u00b009'16.9\
22\u00b018'50.6\"N, 114\u00b013'00.5\ 
22\u00b017'14.4\"N, 114\u00b009'04.0\
22\u00b023'16.3\"N, 114\u00b011'05.5\
22\u00b018'48.3\"N 114\u00b013'28.6\
```

each `\u00b017` is the degree symbol printed in postman, but i dont want them, cant remove it or replace it since each one of them are different, theres no way i can set it manually

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string

Comment: tried all of them, doesnt work

Comment: You've made a mistake, `\u00b0` is the degree symbol, `17` is the minute value.

Answer (score 1):

The degree symbol is `\u00b0`. You can use `str_replace` instead of RegEx to remove it:

```
str_replace('\u00b0', '', $test);
```

Comment: this doesnt work, as i said each unicode is different, i wont be putting each different unicode to the replace function

Comment: The degree symbol itself is `\u00b0`, so the next two digits should be the minutes.

Comment: so dumb lol, i think i copy it wrong