# How to get around SerializeJSON in CF8 encoding non printable characters?

Tags: json, coldfusion

SerializeJSON creates JSON with non printable characters (i.e. ASCII 21)

This is invalid JSON. How can I get round this.

Would a regex removing the non printable characters work?

What regex would remove non printable characters?

Comment: Do you have a script that will test a solution? Or at least a test case? IE: Serialize a structure that contains a query as one of its keys, and you'll see ASCII code 21 in the result. I have an idea but having that test case would really help make sure it's a good answer before I post it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this simple solution was created for cffeed, but your problem is very similar.

First I've tried to use Java library StringEscapeUtils (Commons Lang API), but it didn't escaped my contents properly. Though it is recommended for XML.

So, this cfc method works for me. Maybe will help you too.

```
<cffunction name="cleanXmlString" access="public" returntype="any" output="false" hint="Replace non-valid XML characters">
    <cfargument name="dirty" type="string" required="true" hint="Input string">
    <cfset var cleaned = "" />
    <cfset var patterns = "" />
    <cfset var replaces = "" />

    <cfset patterns = chr(8216) & "," & chr(8217) & "," & chr(8220) & "," & chr(8221) & "," & chr(8212) & "," & chr(8213) & "," & chr(8230) />
    <cfset patterns = patterns & "," & chr(1) & "," & chr(2) & "," & chr(3) & "," & chr(4) & "," & chr(5) & "," & chr(6) & "," & chr(7) & "," & chr(8) />
    <cfset patterns = patterns & "," & chr(14) & "," & chr(15) & "," & chr(16) & "," & chr(17) & "," & chr(18) & "," & chr(19) />
    <cfset patterns = patterns & "," & chr(20) & "," & chr(21) & "," & chr(22) & "," & chr(23) & "," & chr(24) & "," & chr(25) />
    <cfset patterns = patterns & "," & chr(26) & "," & chr(27) & "," & chr(28) & "," & chr(29) & "," & chr(30) & "," & chr(31) />

    <cfset replaces = replaces & "',',"","",--,--,..." />
    <cfset replaces = replaces & ",-, , , , , , , " />
    <cfset replaces = replaces & ", , , , , , " />
    <cfset replaces = replaces & ", , , , , , " />
    <cfset replaces = replaces & ", , , , , , " />

    <cfset cleaned = ReplaceList(arguments.dirty, patterns, replaces) />

    <cfreturn cleaned />

</cffunction>
```